# The Verdier Quotient

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, homological-algebra, triangulated-categories

In A.Neeman's book and D.Murfet's notes I have been reading about the construction of the Verdier quotient of a triangulated category, $\mathscr{T}$, by some triangulated subcategory $\mathscr{C}$. In both places they require that triangulated subcategories be strict (i.e. closed under taking isomorphisms). Is it possible to remove the strictness assumption and still define the Verdier quotient? I have been studying the proof of existence and I haven't been able to find a place with strictness is required. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\mathscr{T}/\mathscr{C}$ still makes sense if $\mathscr{C}$ is not strict, but it's exactly the same as taking the quotient by the "strictification" of $\mathscr{C}$ (i.e., the subcategory consisting of all objects isomorphic to an object of $\mathscr{C}$), so you don't get anything more general.

Comment: Dear Prof. Rickard, Thanks for your answers. I was wondering then, what is the reason that they ask for strictness in the definition of triangulated subcategory?

Comment: @Anette I don't think it has anything to do with taking quotients. It's just that if you didn't, then you'd have to keep worrying about whether an object was really in the subcategory or just isomorphic to something in the subcategory, and so, since assuming strictness almost never causes any problems, it's easier just to assume it.